# C# App.Config location

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a solution with 10 or so projects in it, and have started having issues with SystemConfiguration returning empty configuration instead of locating my App.Config file.

Should I have multiple App.Configs, one for each project (I am assuming and hoping not), if not, where is the best place for it to be located in my projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose one of the projects as the one responsible for maintaining the App.config file. Then for the other projects, use "Add existing item" , navigate to the App.config file and click on the "Add as a link" (it is the right side of the Add button).

Answer (score 1):

You could use build events to overwrite all app.configs with a common one stored in a "main" project or location